# How to bind a key to switching to next window in current monitor in compiz?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, compiz, alt-tab

I'm using compiz 0.8.8 on ArchLinux.

I have two monitors, and each time I use alt-tab to switch to next window, the windows from both monitors shows up. This makes it hard to find a specific window.

Is there any way to bind a key to switching to next window in the current monitor?

So if I have windows A & B on the 1st monitor, and windows C & D on the 2nd monitor, and window A is focused. Is it possible to specify a key similar to Alt-Tab which just switches between windows A & B, and not between windows A, B, C & D?

In KDE4, I can configure the task list on the panels to just show windows on current monitor. So in previous example, in the task list of 1st monitor there are only windows A & B, and in the task list of 2nd monitor there are only windows C & D. Is there similar feature in compiz?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the [`Put` plugin](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Put) in compiz setting manager and set up your key bindings there.

> The Put plugin allows you to put any active window on screen on any viewport, or any position by using keypad bindings
>
> [image]

Comment: I already have it enabled, but Put plugin deals with the place of current window, not switching between windows. There is no key binding there relates to my question.